# Make Dictionary From 2 List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Trying to make dictionary with 2 list one being the key and one being the value but I'm having a problem. This is what I have so far:

```
d={}
for num in range(10):
    for nbr in range(len(key)):
        d[num]=key[nbr]
```

Say my key is a list from 1 to 9, and value list is `[2,4,0,9,6,6,8,6,4,5]`.

How do I assign so it that its like `{0:2, 1:4, etc...}`?

Comment: If "my key is a list from 1 to 9" inclusive, but your value list has TEN entries, then as they say in Shanghai, you are up Suzhou Creek in a bamboo steamer with a broken chopstick for a paddle.

Answer (score 12):

zip() to the rescue!

```
>>> k = range(1,10)   # or some list or iterable of sorts
>>> v = [2,4,0,9,6,6,8,6,4,5]
>>> d = dict(zip(k,v))
>>> d
{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 0, 4: 9, 5: 6, 6: 6, 7: 8, 8: 6, 9: 4}
>>>
```

For more details, see [**zip() built-in function**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), in Python documentation.

Note, regarding range() and the list of "keys".
The question reads "*key is a list from 1 to 9*" (i.e. 9 distinct keys) but the value list shows 10 distinct values.  This provides the opportunity to discuss two points of "detail":

- the range() function in the snippet above will produce the 1 through 9 range, that is because the starting value (1, here), if provided, is always included, whereas the ending value (10, here) is never included.
- the zip() function stops after the iteration which includes the last item of the shortest iterable (in our case, omitting '5', the last value of the list)

Answer (score 6):

If you are mapping indexes specifically, use the `enumerate` builtin function instead of zip/range.

```
dict(enumerate([2,4,0,9,6,6,8,6,4,5]))
```

Comment: Hard to see why you'd need to create a dict that uses a range for a key, unless you're passing it to something that can't use a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
values = [2,4,0,9,6,6,8,6,4,5]
d = dict(zip(range(10), values))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mydict = dict(zip(range(10), [2,4,0,9,6,6,8,6,4,5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

should be something like

```
dict(zip(a,b))
```